# How to render a table in Django from a class with manytomanyfield for all fields selected for an instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, manytomanyfield

I am struggling to render a table view in Django 3.2 that will display data from instance of a class:

```
 class SalesPlan(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer, null=True, on_delete=RESTRICT)
    period = models.DateField()
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, null=True, on_delete=RESTRICT)
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

classes for customer and product:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    belongs_to_sales_channel = models.ForeignKey(SalesChannel, on_delete=RESTRICT)
    customer_portfolio = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductGroup, on_delete=RESTRICT)
    product_subgroup = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubGroup, on_delete=RESTRICT)
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    product_weight_text = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I have tried a function based view and class based view. A class based view gives me one line for one product, since SalesPlan class is set like that. Is there a way to render rows for each product in Customer.customer_portfolio.all() with all data already set and only with quantity for a user to input? I have searched for similar examples, all I found is what I already have: class based view can display a form, for one instance (only one row). I failed using formset, I am currently researching if it's possible using a formset.

Comment: Update: I have managed to display proper number of forms by sending customer's portfolio as context to the view and inside a for loop for each item to display one sales plan form. I will make a custom form and send it to that view to render it in a table in html.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution!
I made a function based view, created a form for a model, then created a formset for that form and passed initial data like so:

```
def create_sales_plan(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(customer_code=pk)
    portfolio = customer.customer_portfolio.all()
    initial = []
    for item in portfolio:
        initial.append({'customer': customer, 'product':item})
    SalesPlanFormSet = formset_factory(SalesPlanForm, extra=0)
    formset = SalesPlanFormSet(initial=initial)
```

This way a formset gets initial data which is a list of dicts which I made "by hand". I really hope this helps other people with similar or same problem, since I was unable to find any resources easily. Now that I have prefilled forms, I will play around to make an html form palatable for entering data (most likely an html table).